# Cublas matrix-matrix multiplication parameters

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I'm trying to do a matrix-matrix multiplication using Cublas but it still not work and I don't figure out the problem.
Since it is the first time I use Cublas I'm not sure that I set the right parameter, especially for the leading dimension

For example:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void mulWithCuda(double *c, const double *a, const double *b, unsigned int size);

int main(){
    const int arraySize = 9;
    const double a[12] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10, 11, 12 };
    const double b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
    double c[12] = { 0 };

    mulWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%lf ", c[i * 3 + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void mulWithCuda(double* c, const double* a, const double* b, unsigned int size){
    double *dev_a = 0;
    double *dev_b = 0;
    double *dev_c = 0;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, 12 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, 12 * sizeof(double));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, 12 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    double alpha = 1.0;
    double beta = 0;

    cublasDgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 4, 3, 3, &alpha, dev_a, 3, dev_b, 3, &beta, dev_c, 3);

    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, 12 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   
    cublasDestroy(handle);

    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
}
```

The two matrix used are:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12


10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90
```

while the output is:

```
 ** On entry to DGEMM  parameter number 8 had an illegal value
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: `alpha` and `beta` are variable allocated on the stack of the host process while I think they should be allocated on the device (or at least be accessible from it).

Comment: @JérômeRichard on the documentation it is written that I could be either host or device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 problems with your code.

1. You are not checking for CUDA errors or cuBLAS errors. CUDA error checking  is described here [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)
2. With proper error checking you will find that `cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);` fails because of illegal memory accesses. `dev_a` and `dev_b` have been allocated with the wrong size. It should be 12 for dev_a and size for dev_b .
3. You make wrong assumption about the memory layout of the matrix. cuBLAS uses a column-major storage format. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#data-layout

This means that the leading dimensions of A and C are 4, not 3. This also means that A and B are

```
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12

and

10 40 70
20 50 80
30 60 90

,respectively
```

Printing of C must also be changed to account for column-major format

Working code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "cublas_v2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void mulWithCuda(double *c, const double *a, const double *b, unsigned int size);

int main(){
    const int arraySize = 9;
    const double a[12] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9, 10, 11, 12 };
    const double b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };
    double c[12] = { 0 };

    mulWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%lf ", c[j * 4 + i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void mulWithCuda(double* c, const double* a, const double* b, unsigned int size){
    double *dev_a = 0;
    double *dev_b = 0;
    double *dev_c = 0;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, 12 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, 12 * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(double));

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, 12 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    double alpha = 1.0;
    double beta = 0;

    cublasDgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 4, 3, 3, &alpha, dev_a, 4, dev_b, 3, &beta, dev_c, 4);

    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, 12 * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   
    cublasDestroy(handle);

    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
}
```

```
Output
380.000000 830.000000 1280.000000 
440.000000 980.000000 1520.000000 
500.000000 1130.000000 1760.000000 
560.000000 1280.000000 2000.000000
```